# Combinatorics: solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=30$ where $\forall i , i\leq x_i \leq 3i$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

While there are some similar problems on this site, I can't seem to find one in which the index $i$ itself has a bearing on the upper bound of each element $x_i$ (assume that $x_i$ is a positive whole number). I would like to verify that I am going in the correct direction with this problem and get some advice on how to continue.

Here is what I have so far:

It's relatively trivial for me to see that

$P(\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=30)=\binom{5+30-1}{30}$.

I am pretty sure that

$P(\forall i, i\leq x_i)=P(\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=15)=\binom{5+15-1}{15}$

The problem I run into is figuring out $P(\forall i, i\leq x_i\leq3i)$. Here is the direction I was heading:

$P(\forall i, i\leq x_i\leq3i)=P(\forall i, i\leq x_i)-P(\forall i, i\leq x_i \cap\exists j, x_j>3j)=$

$=\binom{5+15-1}{15}-\sum_{n=0}^5(-1)^n\binom{5}{n}|P((\forall i, i\leq x_i) \cap (x_1>3\cdot1)\cap...\cap(x_n>3\cdot n))|$

Is this direction correct (regardless of how inefficient it is)? Is there a faster or simpler method?

Comment: Are you looking for the possible number of solutions? What does "$P(\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=30) \ $" mean to you?

Comment: @ThomasBladt Yes. it refers to the # of solutions to x_1+...+x_5=30

Comment: Yes, your strategy is correct.  You can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to remove those solutions that violate at least one of the upper bounds.

Answer (score 2):

The expression $\sum_{i=1}^5x_i=30$ with constraints $i\leq x_i \leq 3i\ $   can be better visualized if we write it as
$$x_1 + x_2 +x_3 +x_4 +x_5 = 30$$
with the constraints $1\le x_1\le 3,$ $\ \ 2\le x_2\le 6,\ \ $$\ \ 3\le x_4\le 9,\ \ $$\ \ 4\le x_4\le 12,\ \ $ and $\ \ 5\le x_5\le 15.\ \ $

This is equivalent to solving the system
$$y_1 +y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5 = 15 $$
with $\ \ 0\le y_1\le 2,\ \ $$\ \ 0\le y_2\le 4,\ \ $$\ \ 0\le y_3\le 6,\ \ $$\ \ 0\le y_4\le 8,\ \ $ and $\ \ 0\le y_5\le 10.$

This is now a standard problem that can  be solved by using the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion. Are you able to take it from here?

Comment: While this answer is technically correct, and is even the same approach that I used when asking the question, I was looking for a faster method of solving this.

Comment: @CluelessButCurious You could use generating functions to solve this problem.  It would take fewer steps, but you might not find it simpler.

Comment: Just like @N.F.Taussig said, you can solve this using generating functions. However, we would end up looking for the coefficient of $x^{15}$ in the expression 
$$(1-x^3)(1-x^5)(1-x^7)(1-x^9)(1-x^{11})\cdot \frac{1}{(1-x)^5}$$
which, in my opinion, is much more troublesome than just using Inclusion-Exclusion for this particular example.  But, if you still want me to present that method, I can happily do so.